# How does SPI subsystem links controller driver and protocol driver?

Tags: linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, spi

Does SPI subsystem is implemented by spi.c and spidev.c is protocol driver and I have read few mentions that we just need to mention spidev in device tree to use this, but how spidev does device specific operation i.e transfers?(it has to know about specific details of spi registers etc. this is where SPI controller driver comes but how these two are linked).Please correct me if I mentioned anything wrong.

Comment: This link would give you more info https://archive.fosdem.org/2017/schedule/event/kernel_spi_subsystem/attachments/slides/1686/export/events/attachments/kernel_spi_subsystem/slides/1686/Groking_the_Linux_SPI_Subsystem.pdf

Comment: Spidev is just a hack and big mistake, to use it properly one needs to have a driver for a certain slave.